# Can't create AVD due to Ok button

Tags: java, android

OK button remains DISABLE

i have filled all fields required but i don't know why ok button always remains disable
 [image]

[image]

Comment: are you using eclipse? 
try to restart eclipse and then open the AVD manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to SDK Manager and install System Images of the corrsponding API first. Then choose this CPU in the third drop down menu from top...

Comment: i have added SDK manager image please tell me which one i have to install

Comment: See API 20 Android 4.4W which you choosed in your AVD. There you nee to check the system images. I suggets to install everything from each API you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the size of SD card then it enables..Like try to give 10-100MB

and also select CPU/ABi filed too

Answer (score -1):

Because behind CPU/ABI it says that there are no system images available.

Comment: It would be helpful to edit in information how to get that to show up though.